# tf.exe folderdiff diffing files in specific folders

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

I want to be able to diff all my app.config files that resides in folders called MessagingService. I have read the documentation on the tf.exe about 50 times now, and I can't understand that the syntax should be different than:

```
tf.exe treediff $/myproject/main $/myproject/prod /filter:"app.config;MessagingService\" /r
```

but this leaves no results. As far as I can understand the folder inclusion mask does not behave as expected, because the following line works fine:

```
tf.exe treediff $/myproject/main $/myproject/prod /filter:"app.config;!MessagingService\" /r
```

but of course it displays only the app.configs I'm not interested in :)

Any enlightening comments are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this one ...

tf.exe treediff $/myproject/main $/myproject/prod /filter:"app.config;*MessagingService*\" /r

I believe stars are needed after and before MessagingService word because "app.config" IS the entire filename but MessagingService word IS NOT the entire path value, it is just a part of the actual file path.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't seem to work in my case. When I use `/filter:"app.config"` I get many diffs, for instance `$/myproject/Main/Accounting/MessagingService/App.config -
        $/myproject/prod/Accounting/MessagingService/App.config` but when adding the folder with wildcards as you suggested, I get none.